# Howto send encrypted messages between python and php using blowfish for encryption?

Tags: php, python, django, blowfish, encryption-symmetric

I want to encrypt a message in php with a known password using blowfish. I would then be like to decrypt this message in python.

This is useful even if you want to encrypt in one language and decrypt elsewhere.

I searched quite extensively but could not find any conclusive solution, so I thought to record my findings.

Note it is quite simple to encrypt/decrypt in same language such as python or php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is very simple but it took me a while to figure out.

***Blowfish Params***

- Password should be of length 16
- use mode MODE_ECB.
- ***Data being encrypted length should be always divisible by 16 pad by spaces or anyother char. I have taken a 16 length data string in example below.***

php code:

```
<?php
$passw='secretPassword12';
$ntext='helloWorld123456';
$enc = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $passw, $ntext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
echo '<div>'.$enc.'</div';
```

This outputs 3C8f2kaD8Of0INYk3l9qEg==
python code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
passw='secretPassword12'
ntext='helloworld123456'

cipher=Blowfish.new(passw, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
encStr=b64encode(cipher.encrypt(data))
print encStr
```

This code outputs 3C8f2kaD8Of0INYk3l9qEg== too

Now suppose you want to decrypt some string in python encrypted in php. First do b64decode and then decrypt the result.

```
Remember to pad your data such that the len is divisible by 16.
```

Happy encrypting and decrypting!!!

Comment: It's hard to see how Blowfish in ECB mode, where you require calling code to do the padding, is particularly useful.

Comment: Took you a while?  3minutes? :)

Comment: @sdolgy you would think so, but try this `cipher=Blowfish.new(passw, Blowfish.MODE_CFB)` Then, do this `print cipher.decrypt(cipher.encrypt('my test string'))`. Now why does that happen

Comment: @KSB: It happens because you are using completely the wrong tools for this job. You should be using an encryption library that provides the features you need, including sane chaining and padding.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for your reply, Can you please elaborate? By padding you mean that data should be of length in multiples of 16, so I did that here. `cipher.decrypt(cipher.encrypt('1234567887654321'))` What is chaining?

Comment: Please learn some of the basics of cryptography before you attempt to write code. It's like you've just built a suspension bridge and are now asking me what cement and steel are. I'm not trying to be mean or rude, but real damage can be done this way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No offense taken, I really have very less understanding of encryption but I do need to use one. But should not a library be easy to use without knowing every details behind the curtains. [link](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) is the official documentation of the python library and even my little try of decrypt(encrypt) doesnt work with official code. This is just FYI, I would try to read up some background of Encryption. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it should be that way in an ideal world, but unfortunately it is not. There are just too many different requirements and threat models for it to be possible to just grab a library and stick it in there and make it work. You really do have to know what you're doing. If you actually need it to be secure against a real threat, you need an expert to design it. This really is like building a suspension bridge that real cars and trucks will drive over. You can't just hook together a bunch of standard girders and beams. You have to design it, and design it right -- or it will collapse.